# Date range with regex or someting else

Tags: java, regex, date, validation, range

Now, I use regex to validate my date which is

```
String regex = "^(?:(?:31(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$|^(?:29(\\/|-|\\.)0?2\\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])(\\/|-|\\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$|(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})(\\/|-|\\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\\5(?:0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])$|^(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(\\/|-|\\.)0?2\\6(29)$|^(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})(?:(?:(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\\8(?:29|30))|(?:(\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02])\\9(?:31)))$\n";
```

However, I also want to set a range for my date.And max min date should current date and x(desired year) year before.

How can I do it?

Comment: Provide minimal reproducible code.

Comment: Please give example of what a date range may look like so we can understand the format it should adhere to. You should not use a regular expression but rather a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Doing it by regex will be unnecessarily complex and error-prone. Do it using the Date-Time API as suggested in [the answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69451951/10819573).

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. It’s much better suited for validating date formats and date ranges. A thing like finding x years ago is trivial.

Not knowing your format here’s a sketch that you may modify to your needs.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-u", Locale.ROOT);

/**
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if dates are out of range or the string is in an incorrect format
 * @throws DateTimeParseException if a date is invalid or has incorrect format
 */
public static void validateDateRange(int maxAgeYears, String dateRangeString) {
    String[] strings = dateRangeString.split(" - ");
    
    if (strings.length != 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect format; give two dates separated by \" - \".");
    }
    
    // The calls to parse may throw DateTimeParseException
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse(strings[0], PARSER);
    LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse(strings[1], PARSER);
    
    if (start.isAfter(end)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dates are in the wrong order; give start before end.");
    }
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    if (start.isBefore(today.minusYears(maxAgeYears))) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start is too long ago; give start of range that reaches at most " + maxAgeYears + " years back.");
    }
    if (end.isAfter(today)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("End is in the future; give end as current day or before.");
    }
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    validateDateRange(4, "1-1-2020 - 31-12-2020");
```

This runs tacitly without any exception being thrown

```
    validateDateRange(4, "1/1-2020 - 31/12-2020");
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
> Text '1/1-2020' could not be parsed at index 1

```
    validateDateRange(4, "1-1-2017 - 31-12-2021");
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Start
> is too long ago; give start of range that reaches at most 4 years back.

PS By Stack Overflow standards you didn’t deserve this answer. You need to make your requirements and your format in particular much clearer and to show a greater effort on your side. I understand that you are new here and chose to be gentle this time.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.